# Running spring tool suite on Ubuntu command line (Windows Subsystem Linux)

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu-18.04

I activated Windows Subsystem Linux and installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft store. I installed Spring tool suite on Ubuntu through wget and extracting it.

However, I don't know how to start the sts application from the command line. I only see instructions on Ubuntu Desktop, but the Ubuntu on WSL doesn't have a Desktop mode.

I tried searching for "How to run spring tool suite on Ubuntu command line window" but see nothing that helps me.

I want to run Spring tool suite from Ubuntu Command line window

Comment: Spring Tool Suite is a GUI tool; and Ubuntu on WSL **does** have a desktop mode. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` Or just run STS in Windows. There really isn't any special need to run it in Ubuntu is there? What exactly are you trying to do? And why?

Comment: I'm new to both Linux and Kafka. I see that I've to write Java programs for Kafka, and that it's recommended to run Kafka on Linux. That's why I was thinking installing STS or IntelliJ will make it easier to stay on the same OS. Thanks for responding to my question.

Comment: You can run it in WSL. You need to install X client on Windows and the supporting files in Ubuntu. Then follow the install procedure from Spring to get it installed for linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can get X started on the WSL and run Spring's Tools. Follow this tutorial first and get X running on both the WSL and Windows. Then install Java as required on the Linux WSL. Lastly, follow Spring's guide to installing Tools on Linux.

https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx

This is the second time I have followed the tutorial and I have had luck both times!